# error_log reports not showing in specified path

Tags: php, apache, debugging, digital-ocean, ini-set

I have this debug function to show runtime errors and some messages.

```
/**
 * Debug logs
 * @param string $msg Log message
 */
function logMsg(?string $msg)
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors', true);
    ini_set('display_errors', false);
    ini_set('log_errors', true);
    ini_set("error_log", SERVER_ROOT . "debug.log");

    if (DEBUG_MODE) {

        $bt = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1);
        $caller = array_shift($bt);
        $File = basename($caller["file"]);
        $Line = $caller['line'];

        error_log("$msg [$File On line $Line]");
    }
}
```

This works well on local but now that I deploy my web-app on digital ocean droplet the errors are being printed in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` instead of `myapp/debug.log`.

I want to know if there is something more I have to do to set this function to work properly?